# Есть ли другие способы использовать linear-gradient

Tags: css

Я хотел изменить цвет букв на основе градиента.

```
color: linear-gradient(0deg, blue, pink, red);
```

Типа так. Как будет правильно?

Comment: правильно будет использовать svg

Comment: как.И где именно нужно использовать svg

Comment: можно указать в hex или в rgba - в rgba можно будет прозрачность ещё сделать

Comment: Можно ещё использовать `hsl` (Пример: `hsl(360, 100%, 50%)`).